# use indexOf() method to find word that consists "to"

Tags: java

I am writing a program that count how many words that has "do" in it. I use indexOf() method to do it. for example, when I write "actualWord.indexOf('a'));" the program will show how many letter 'a' appear in a sentence or words. I write "actualWord.indexOf("do") and I think the program will count how many words that contains "do" in it and then show it. When I test the program, I write words "don't doing do doable douche dough double", the output should be seven because there are 7 words that contains "do". But my program does not do that. In fact, when I write "actualWord.indexOf("do");" and I try the code by write "do do do" the program said I have -1 words that have "do". I am confused now. Can someone tell me where I do wrong? Thank you so much for your help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TheFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String yourSentence;

        System.out.print("Enter your word here:");
        yourSentence = input.nextLine();

        String actualWord = yourSentence;

        System.out.printf ("%s\n", actualWord);
        System.out.print ("Found index the :");
        System.out.println (actualWord.indexOf("do"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
System.out.println (actualWord.indexOf('at'));
```

to

```
System.out.println (actualWord.indexOf("at"));
```

`'at'` is invalid character literal

Comment: I make a dumb mistakes. okay, already correct it. but the output isn't what I am looking for. I just re-edit my questions. thank you so much for helping me

Comment: indexOf() doesn't give you how many times the term appears, it gives you the first index at which it is found and -1 if not found

Comment: read API doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

The method `s.indexOf("do")` does *not* return how many occurrences of "do" occur in the string `s`. It returns the position (index) of the first occurrence of "do". So, `"do do do".indexOf("do");` returns 0, as the first occurrence of "do" occurs at index 0 in the string.

If you want to count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string, you will have to write that yourself. You can use the overloaded version `indexOf(String, int)` for that. This method returns the first index of the substring *after* a given index.

```
public static int count(String haystack, String needle)
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    while (index >= 0) {
        count++;
        index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
'do'
```

is not a character. It's a `String`. Try

```
"do"
```

and

```
actualWord.indexOf("at") // not 'at'
```

**Edit**

Why not start by writing a function to count the number of times the `String` occurs like

```
public static int countOccurences(String str, String in) {
    int count = 0;
    int pos = str.indexOf(in);
    for (; pos > -1; pos = str.indexOf(in, pos + 1)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you can call that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourSentence = "don't doing do doable douche dough double";
    System.out.println(countOccurences(yourSentence, "do"));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
7
```

Comment: I see. so I have to use " " instead of ' '

Comment: @NumbNuts Edited to give you a simple method to do what you seem to actually want.